# HTML fieldset, center not working

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I want to center a fieldset but I want it to be resize due to its content, so I added the attr `display: inline-block;` to the style, which makes that, but it moves the fieldset to the left...

I was using `margin: 0 auto;` to center the fieldset but its not working anymore...

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/24n2K/12/)

Comment: your `display: inline-block` is indeed the problem.

Comment: can you please post your code.

Comment: The code is already posted on the "Here's an example" link

Comment: Yes, but the code should be *here* as well, in order to protect against JS Fiddle breaking/going down. Also, to make the questions self-contained, and allow people to look at the code to see if there's any obvious errors.

Comment: You're right, I'll do it on my next question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add `text-align: center;` to your `fieldset` CSS rules, it seems to work (centering the `label`s against the `input`s below).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/24n2K/17/).

---

**Edited**

As it's the `fieldset` that needs to be centred, rather than its content, simply add the `text-align: center;` to the parent element of the `fieldset`. Normally this should be the `form` element (or a parent `fieldset`, since nesting is valid), but as there is no `form` in the linked example I've applied the `text-align` to the `body` element: [updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/24n2K/25/).

Comment: That's centering the content of the fieldset, not the fieldset.

Comment: Oops, sorry; I clearly didn't read the question closely enough. See the updated answer! =)

Comment: Good point, I understand, but if I want to keep the content of the fieldset aligned to the left, should I have to use `text-align:left` in the fieldset class?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid so; because `text-align` is inherited.